# На сайте не работает авторизация через ВК

Tags: node.js, вконтакте, passport

Использую на своем сайте авторизацию через VK. Сайт сделан на nodejs. Для авторизации используется модуль passport-vkontakte. Пробелма заключаеться в следуюшем, авторизация работает не у всех. у некоторых выводиться ошибка.

```
TokenError: Code is invalid or expired. 
at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse(/root/nfsnlsite/node_modules/passport-vkontakte/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:320:12)
at Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/root/nfsnlsite/node_modules/passport-vkontakte/lib/passport-vkontakte/strategy.js:176:54)
at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/root/nfsnlsite/node_modules/passport-vkontakte/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:367:16) 
at /root/nfsnlsite/node_modules/passport-vkontakte/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45 
at /root/nfsnlsite/node_modules/passport-vkontakte/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:191:18 
at passBackControl (/root/nfsnlsite/node_modules/passport-vkontakte/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9) 
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/root/nfsnlsite/node_modules/passport-vkontakte/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7) 
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:920:16 at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)
```

До этого грешил на сохранение сессии в базу, перевел хранение сессии в memcach. Но проблема не решилась. Люди у которых вход выполнить не удалось отмечают что чистка куки и смена браузера проблему не решает.

Comment: А дальше что в стектрейсе?

Comment: @PavelMayorov
`at /root/nfsnlsite/node_modules/passport-vkontakte/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:191:18 at passBackControl (/root/nfsnlsite/node_modules/passport-vkontakte/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9) at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/root/nfsnlsite/node_modules/passport-vkontakte/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7) at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20) at _stream_readable.js:920:16 at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)`

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос. Такие простыни неудобно в комментариях читать.

Comment: Судя по всему, у вас ошибка произошла вот тут: `oauth2.js:191:18`, при запросе access token у сервера vk.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Отредактировал добавил.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ну этот момент я понел, тут больше вопрос почему так происходит и только с некоторыми пользователями. Причем это не у одного такая проблема. Пробывали удалять в натсройках вк у человека приложение и давать разряшения по новой. Чистить куки, чистил сам сервер в бд сессии, ну потом прееключился на memcach